# How can I run a test that compares js output with ruby output

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a rails environment, I have implemented some moderately complicated math in javascript. I've implemented the same math in ruby. If ever they don't agree, I page myself which may or may not wake me up, which is generally undesirable.

Currently I have a small handful of tests that automate the browser and make sure the results agree, but that is very limiting because they're so slow. What I'd like is to be able to call the js and the ruby directly, with the same inputs, and verify that I get the same outputs. This way I could run thousands of tests with randomized inputs and feel moderately confident that I wasn't running into differences in the way numbers are handled in the respective languages.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Is the JS held in a database? How do you expect to extract it and compare with Ruby? Can you post some code examples, showing a case where JS and Ruby _do_ output the same value?

Comment: What are using for testing capybara/selenium?

Comment: why do you need a browser? why not simply use nodejs to run the javascript?  or perhaps : https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

Comment: I use the browser to test these now only because I'm testing the whole page where the js runs, and part of testing that page is testing that the server agrees with the client-side calculation.

execjs looks like it might be exactly what I'm asking for...